# Place sliding divs at a fixed bottom position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently using [this bit of code](https://jsfiddle.net/PJxV9/1/) (adapted to my needs) to create a bootstrap carrousel-like.

I have successfully place it to the bottom of my page, but I would like to make it `fixed`.

I assume that I just need to add:

```
.block{
  bottom: 0; 
  position: fixed; 
}
```

Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9s0pLv1s/).

What is that not the way to go?

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: You should fix the `.box` not the `.block` [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/PJxV9/16/) -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add those attributes to

```
.box {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
}
```

[Edited fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkjegxjg/)

---

other approach is to add a wrapper above the box and set its height 100%-"the .box's height".
this would stick the box on the bottom of the monitor. the part above then would be scrollable.
[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/m2dtusyt/1/)